# Calculating running time of a while loop

Tags: c++, algorithm, time-complexity

I am just starting with algorithms and I am trying to find out the running time in terms of 'n' for the while loop below.

```
int k=1;
while(k<n-k){
k+=k;
}
```

Here n>2. I understand that the value of k doubles everytime and the loop runs only once, once k value becomes greater than n/2. But I am having difficulty in expressing the same in terms of 'n'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's worth to list the important points:

- `k` doubles on every loop iteration
- your loop condition can be rewritten as: `while(2*k < n)`*

The essential question is: *how many times I have to **double** the `k`, untill **`k` doubled** will be equal or greater than `n`?*

This is fairly easy. This is exactly how logarithms work. Take a number `2`, for example. How many times do I have to double it to reach, let's say, 1000? The answer is log<sub>2</sub>1000 rounded up.

Essentially, your algorithm is `log_2(n) - 1`, which means that your algorithm runs in *logarithmic time complexity*.

---

<sub>*As **François Andrieux** correctly stated in his comment, while mathematically this statement is true, this is not always the case in programming, due to the representation limits of data types. For large `k`s, the expression `2*k` might cause an overflow and invalidate the whole expression, while with the same input the expression `k < n-k` will behave correctly.</sub>

Comment: While it doesn't change the correctness of the answer, I'd like to point out that since `k` is a `signed int`, `2*k < n` is not quite equivalent to `k < n-k` since the first form may overflow if `n` is large enough.

Comment: That's a very valid point that should be addressed. I will add this comment to my answer shortly. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
  while(k<n-k)
     k+=k;
```

with equivalent

```
  while(2*k<n)
    k*=2
```

the last is definitely `O(log(n))` - it makes `log2(n)-1` steps

Answer (score 1):

Expression `k < n-k` simplifies to `k < n/2`.

Time Complexity should be `O(log(n))`  with base being 2

```
K = 1 -> 2 -> 4 -> 8 -> ... -> m iterations

2^(m-1) < n/2

m-1 < log2(n/2)

m ~ log2(n)
```